# while read loop and variables

Tags: bash, variable, read

I am seeking your council .. as i'm hitting a wall ....  in a bash script

I'd like to read all of the lines of a given file to an array, and run 
a set of statements to determine if said args are true or false .

here is the example file id like to pull values from , as an array, per line :

```
2019-11-07 10:07:08,000 p=28290 u=root |  ansclient2                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
2019-11-07 12:48:42,438 p=1830 u=root |  ansclient                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

so, im trying -

```
while read -r row ; do
    args=${row[@]}
    #pid
    pc=${row[2]}
    #hostname
    hn=${row[5]}
    #failed row
    st=${row[10]}
    echo $pc
    echo $hn
    echo $st
    if [ $st -eq "failed=0" ] ; then echo "true" 
    else
        echo "failed is something other than 0"
        echo $hn $st
    fi
```

It's not working as expected .. im looking to loop thru each of the lines , as an array , [while true] ; and compare the value of 'failed=' to determine if its 0 or other than that.

If someone can help, i'd really appreciate it ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but (1) your `read` command needs ` -a` if you want to read into an array (2) `-eq` is an integer test: to test for string equality use `[ "$st" = "failed=0" ]` (3) your `do` loop is missing its `done`

Answer (score 3):

For reading files like that, you better use `awk`:

```
awk '{
    print $3
    print $6
    print $11
    if ($11 == "failed=0") print "true"
    else print "failed is something other than 0"
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

As @pLumo said, `awk` is the better tool if you just want to print out. If you want to do other fancy things with these variables and need them within your bash script therefore, then modifying your `read` command to directly read an array is the right choice.

If you need both, the entire line (the variable `row`) and the array (the variable `args`), you may write this:

```
while IFS= read -r row; do
  read -r -a args <<< "$row"
  # ...
done
```

By default, `IFS` is set to all whitespaces. If the input is a CSV file with semicolons separating the columns, you can set the `IFS` accordingly:

```
while IFS= read -r row; do
  IFS=';' read -r -a args <<< "$row"
  # ...
done
```

Comment: Hello All,thank you for your suggestions . So , here is what I went with , for the time being -- provided by  - pLumo 


the modded code -

Answer (score -1):

From pLumo's answer - here is what I went with -

```
#!/bin/bash


#transform the log
grep -i recap -A1 ansible.log |grep -iv recap |grep -v "\-\-" > ansible2.log

#get status of output of said ansible2.log with a success status along with the hostname
#of the job

awk '{print $3, $6, $10, $11
if ($10 == "unreachable=0") print "DEVICE WAS REACHABLE 0"
else if($10 != "unreachable=0") print "DEVICE WAS UNREACHABLE 1"

if ($10 == "unreachable=0")
if ($11 == "failed=0") print "NOTHING FAILED, was successful run"
else print $11 " is something other than 0"
else print $10 " was unreachable" }' ansible2.log
```

I would also like to use rexkogitans `IFS` method, but was not able to get it working properly . .
I was trying to get (while)IFS to read the log line by line, getting the values to populate , so i would be able to iterate thru them .. instead, my code would endlessly loop, or just not populate the vars correctly :(

I get WAY to much output from this code --  [like 112 lines  , from a 4 line log file .. cant be right! ]

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line 
do 
for i in $line
do
echo "pid is $i ${os[1]} , host is $i ${os[2]}, success is $i ${os[3]}, failed is $i ${os[4]}"
echo "done for that line"
done
done <ans.log
```

I'm getting the following output for example -

```
pid is 2019-11-07  , host is 2019-11-07 , success is 2019-11-07 , failed is 2019-11-07 
done for that line
pid is 10:07:08,000  , host is 10:07:08,000 , success is 10:07:08,000 , failed is 10:07:08,000 
done for that line
pid is p=28290  , host is p=28290 , success is p=28290 , failed is p=28290 
done for that line
pid is u=root  , host is u=root , success is u=root , failed is u=root 
done for that line
pid is |  , host is | , success is | , failed is |
```

It seems that its failing to populate the vars correctly, instead looping thru the
one var each time, instead of calling them properly .. any ideas there ?

Thank you for all your help, sorry i didnt answer back sooner, needed to test, and 
work overnight doing sysadmin work stuff .

thanks,
=-brian

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to the question. If you have issues with any of the given answer, use the comment field on that answer to ask for clarifications. As for following [rexkogitans' solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/552148/116858), you don't follow his solution at all (I see no `read -a` in your code).